# Coloring Polygons from a Fusion Table without a numeric basis

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am converting a Google Map that uses v2 of the API and a hosted KML file to Fusion Tables and v3 of the API.

The end result of what I'm looking for (the v2 map) is here:
http://www.willoughby-ind.com/findarep.aspx

The v3 map I'm working on is here:
http://www.willoughby-ind.com/Management/FindaRepGoogleMapsv3.aspx

I've been able to add all of the state boundaries for the US and canada using this piece of code:

```
layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(
        query: {
            select: "kml_4326",
            from: "420419",
            where: "name_0 IN ('United States of America','Canada')"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 8,
        templateId: 1
    });
```

It highlights the states and provinces just as I want, but I need to shade each region in a different color (or at least 4-5 colors). I don't have a numeric basis FOR this shade, just want to set each region apart from those around it, instead of coloring the whole map in the default color of red.

I've looked at some of the styling examples of Buckets and Gradients, but they're all based on a numeric value in the table, which I don't have. How might I go about about doing this?

I'm also going to need to produce a callback event when a region is clicked on, but I imagine this will be rather straightforward.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with State Name (name_1) to color mapping and merge that with the original table (on name_1):

I took the colors out of your old map, and merged them into this table (there were a couple missing):

[Merged table with colors](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1drRN_EVfteimKhXcLX9kj9vxxU9sSJoRsumrTMw#map%3aid=3)

CSV I used for the "color" table:

```
name_1, colour
Alaska, ff0000
Alabama, ff0000
Arkansas, ff0000
Arizona, ff0000
California, 880000
Colorado, 880000
Connecticut, 880000
Delaware, 880000
Florida, 8800ff
Georgia, 880000
Hawaii, 00ff00
Iowa, 00ff00
Idaho, 00ff00
Illinois, 00ffff
Indiana, 00ff00
Kansas, 008800
Kentucky, 008800
Louisiana, 008800
Massachusetts, 0000ff
Maryland, 0000ff
Maine, 0000ff
Michigan, FF0000
Minnesota, 0000ff
Missouri, 000088
Mississippi, 000088
Montana, 000088
North Carolina, ffff00
North Dakota, ffff00
Nebraska, ffff00
New Hampshire, 00ffff
New Jersey, ffff00
New Mexico, 00ffff
Nevada, 00ffff
New York, 00ffff
Ohio, ff8800
Oklahoma, ff00ff
Oregon, ff00ff
Pennsylvania, ff00ff
Rhode Island, ffff00
South Carolina, ff8800
South Dakota, ff8800
Tennessee, ff8800
Texas, 00ff88
Utah, 00ff88
Virginia, 00ff88
Vermont, 88ff00
Washington, 88ff00
Wisconsin, 0088ff
West Virginia, 0088ff
Wyoming, ff0088
Alberta, ff0000
Saskatchewan, 880000
Manitoba, 00ff00
Prince Edward Island, 0000ff
Nova Scotia, 000088
Newfoundland and Labrador,  ff00ff
Ontario, ff00ff
New Brunswick, ffff00
British Columbia, 00ff88
Quebec, 88ff00
Puerto Rico, 000000
Yukon, ff0088
Northwest Territories, ff8800
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to learn how to do that table merge on my own, but can save that for another day. So can I now take the "from" setting in my JavaScript and change it from 420419 to the value in the URL you gave me - 1drRN_EVfteimKhXcLX9kj9vxxU9sSJoRsumrTMw ? Is that a permanent link, or is it tied to your account, a temporary query, etc.? I'm new to Fusion Tables and these documents and certainly don't want to link to something that may go away in a day / week / month.